# Execute SQL Server stored procedure through SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ssis

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Carrier_Scan_Compliance]
     (@RETAILERID  INT OUTPUT,
      @SYSTEM_ID  VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @RETAILERID = 2
    SET @SYSTEM_ID = 'DMASOS'
    ...
END
```

I have created a SSIS package using a **Execute SQL Task** in the control flow.

These are my **Execute SQL Task** editor settings:

[image]

This are my **Variable** settings:

[image]

These are my **Parameter Mapping** settings:

[image]

When I run the SSIS package, I get an error:

> Error: 0xC002F210 at Execute SQL Stored Procedure (to copy data from 'BI-Datatrunk' source table) Task, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "exec  = [sp_Carrier_Scan_Compliance] ? OUTPUT, ? O..." failed with the following error: "Incorrect syntax near '='.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
>
> Task failed: Execute SQL Stored Procedure (to copy data from 'BI-Datatrunk' source table) Task
>   Warning: 0x80019002 at Carrier_Scan_Compliance_SP: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.

I am not sure what I am missing.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You have to set "ResultSet" fro m"None" to "full record" (or something like this... otherwise Exec SQL Task has no result set...

Comment: @Tyron78 If I add that, I am getting below error `Error: 0xC00291E2 at Execute SQL Stored Procedure (to copy data from 'BI-Datatrunk' source table) Task, Execute SQL Task: There is an invalid number of result bindings returned for the ResultSetType: "ResultSetType_Rowset".`

Comment: Remove the equals sign from `exec =` from the SQL Statement

Comment: @cool-br33ze If I do that I am getting below error message `Error: 0xC002F210 at Execute SQL Stored Procedure (to copy data from 'BI-Datatrunk' source table) Task, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "exec   [sp_Carrier_Scan_Compliance] ? OUTPUT, ? OU..." failed with the following error: "The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_Carrier_Scan_Compliance', database 'DATAK', schema 'dbo'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.`

Comment: `"The EXECUTE permission was denied..."`... !?

Comment: @tyron78 I  can able to execute the Stored Procedure directly through SSMS. But if I run the query via SSIS then I get the error

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I just created the procedure in a Test DB and modifies the exec sql as follows: change back to "Resultset none", change SQL statement to `EXEC [sp_Carrier_Scan_Compliance] ? OUT, ? OUT`. The remaining settings I left untouched / as you described - worked like a charm...

Comment: @marc-s thanks, I will update to different name with out sp_

Comment: @tyron78 I was executing Stored Procedure in SSMS through different user account. Its working now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key part of the last error is

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object
>   'sp_Carrier_Scan_Compliance', database 'DATAK', schema 'dbo'."

You need to assign EXECUTE permissions to the SQL user executing the Proc

```
USE DATAK
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON sp_Carrier_Scan_Compliance TO <sql user>
GO
```

Comment: @cool-br33ze I  can able to execute the Stored Procedure directly through SSMS. But if I run the query via SSIS then I get the error

Comment: Are running the Proc in SSMS as the same sql user that the SSIS package is using?

Comment: have you confirmed that they're both the same db on the same server?  Check the connection string on the data source in the SSIS package

Comment: >>> Yes under same user<<< You only think so, but it's not true. Instead of your exec proc try to exec EXEC('SELECT DB_NAME, USER, ORIGINAL_LOGIN()') and check if it's same db, same user, same login.

Comment: @cool-br33ze Yes, just checked deeply. I was executing Stored Procedure in SSMS through different user account

Comment: @sepupic you are correct I was executing Stored Procedure in SSMS through different user account

Comment: Just grant EXECUTE permission to ssis account to resolve your issue

Comment: @user2331670 Glad I could help.  Don't forget to give some love (tick and upvote) to my answer. :-)